# Django not showing up in requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I have a repository that contains a web app powered by Django. Since I have done everything in a virtual environment, I figured `pip freeze > requirements.txt` would result in django being mentioned in `requirements.txt`. But no. Here is what it looks like:

```
mongoengine==0.13.0
pymongo==3.5.1
python2==1.2
pytz==2017.2
six==1.10.0
```

No django. And django is installed in the right place, as you can see me prove here:

```
>>> import django
>>> django.__file__
'/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py'
```

The project is in this location:

```
(workout) Sahands-MBP:workout sahandzarrinkoub$ ls
README.md       include         pip-selfcheck.json  sketches
bin         lib         requirements.txt    workout
(workout) Sahands-MBP:workout sahandzarrinkoub$ pwd
/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout
```

Why isn't django included in requirements.txt? How can I trust that `pip freeze` will produce the correct requirements for the project?

EDIT1:

Another thing I noticed is that `python3` isn't included in `requirements.txt` either, even though that is what `python` in my virtualenv points to.

EDIT2:

FYI, I'm activating my environment before running `pip freeze`. `which pip` returns `/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/bin/pip`.

Comment: Are you activating your virtualenv before running pip freeze? Can you post the results of 'which pip' after you source your virtual env?

Comment: Done, see my edit